# Unity 2D/3D - Making a computer opponent (AI) for a match-3 game

Tags: artificial-intelligence, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm looking for guidance/advice on where to start to create a computer AI opponent for a match-3 game. This issue has been stumping me for years (literally), as I've not been able to figure it out. I've exhausted Google in finding this answer.

Sample match-3 games that have a computer opponent include: [Puzzle Quest](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITAuIf05ck4) and [Crystal Battle](http://www.juggernart.com/games/free-online-puzzle-games/crystal-battle.html).

What programming methodologies are used in creating an AI opponent like this, and how can I apply it to Unity 2D scripting? Where/how can I start? I am mainly looking for a tutorial or something to get me started in the right direction. I realize this is not a quick an easy thing to do, but I would like to attempt it step by step so I can better understand things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question might be more suited to [http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize such a place existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- Generating possible moves
- Choosing the best move

If your board is reasonably small, you can simply brute-force both of them. For all positions in your grid check if you can move it up, down, left or right, and you have your move generator. (You should have checking for valid moves already implemented for a single-player version of the game).

Choosing the best move will be a bit more tricky, because you have to evaluate each move. Common way to do this is [MiniMax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax) method. General idea is that you build a tree of all possible moves in the next couple of turns and assign a score to each leaf. Then you reduce the tree so that parent node becomes max(leaves) if it is AIs turn to move, and min(leaves) if player moves. You end up with the score for your move at root.

Great resource for basic AI programming like this is [Chess Programming Wiki](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/) (you won't need 90% of what is described there. Start with MiniMax and AlphaBeta algorithms).

On the other hand, for the simplest possible AI you can just pick a move at random, match-3 games are not the most demanding when it comes to planning your moves.

EDIT: As an afterthought, the following seems like a reasonable AI strategy for a match-3 game:

Assuming all the random gems added after each move cannot be matched in any way:

1. Pick a move that makes my opponent unable to move (has no child nodes).
2. If 1. is not possible, pick any move that guarantees me another move no matter which move my opponent picks (no child node is a leaf).
3. If 2. is not possible, pick random move.